# XSLT transformation depending on parent items value

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm trying to get following to work.

XML:

```
<Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<Result ID="4,New">
    <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
    <ID />
    <z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x0100142A0297E606694EA802A784F2232A63" ows_Title="APT.2342362" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="APT.2342362" ows_LinkTitle="APT.2342362" ows_LinkTitle2="APT.2342362" ows_FacilityNumber="2342362" ows_Status="New" ows_TenantArea="17;#Africa &amp; Asia Pacific" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</Result>
<Result ID="5,New">
    <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
    <ID />
    <z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x0100142A0297E606694EA802A784F2232A63" ows_Title="APT.2342342" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="APT.2342342" ows_LinkTitle="APT.2342342" ows_LinkTitle2="APT.2342342" ows_FacilityNumber="2342342" ows_Status="New" ows_TenantArea="17;#Africa &amp; Asia Pacific" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</Result>
```

my XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="ShowVariables">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()='z:row']">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to check for the "ErrorCode" if the value is "0x00000000" or not and process the rows separately on that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parent-selector `..` to check the parent. Remember to add the correct namespace to the stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="ShowVariables">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()='z:row']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../soap:ErrorCode = '0x00000000'">
                    ErrorCode reached
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tried this, it seems that the <xls:when statement is just being ignored it goes always to the "otherwise" bracket.

Comment: It was because of the SOAP namespace. I added it to the stylesheet (you should add the `z:` namespace as well) and amended the check.

Answer (score 1):

An other way to make a condition on ErrorCode is to create separate templates.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//soap:Result"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="soap:Result[soap:ErrorCode = '0x00000000']">
        Error detected
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="soap:Result[soap:ErrorCode != '0x00000000']">
        <xsl:value-of select="z:row/@ows_Title"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```